# Which set is this bag 3 from?

Tags: set-identification

[image]

This is the bag. Please help me identify and find instructions.

Comment: Do you have any other pictures of the bag?  The glare on the bag makes it hard to see the parts.  A picture of the back in better light would make this much easier.

Answer (score 4):

THe appearance of  [part 973pb2859c01 - Torso Scuba Vest with Utility Belt with Pouches and Lavender Tentacles Pattern / Yellow Arms / Black Hands](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973pb2859c01&name=Torso%20Scuba%20Vest%20with%20Utility%20Belt%20with%20Pouches%20and%20Lavender%20Tentacles%20Pattern%20/%20Yellow%20Arms%20/%20Black%20Hands&category=%5BMinifig,%20Torso%20Assembly%5D#T=S&C=55&O=%7B%22color%22:55,%22iconly%22:0%7D) means this is from one of [these 3 The Lego Ninjago Movie sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=973pb2859c01&in=S).

The dominance of Red and Black bricks, combined with the presence of [part 78c02 - Flat Silver Hose, Ribbed 7mm D. 2L](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=78c02&idColor=95) narrows it down to set [70615 - Fire Mech](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70615-1).

[image]